# My monitor keeps turning on and off when trying to access the bios

Tags: bios

I'm using a samsung quad HD space monitor which I just bought.
I have a a windows 10 pc with a msi motherboard. Every time I try to open the bios screen the monitor will turn on and off. When the screen is on it doesnt display anything.(just a black screen)

Comment: Perhaps attach a different monitor and then update BIOS, Chipset and Video drivers. Then see if BIOS opens in the Samsung monitor

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, my monitor's firmware was out of date

Comment: It might be useful to include how you updated the monitor's firmware